# Select Distinct Field on Join

Tags: mysql, join, select, where-clause

I am joining two large tables in MySQL based on a unique identifier they both share. Because there are a large number of fields, I do not want to list out all fields after SELECT. Instead I want to select all fields, but I do not want recurring fields (the shared unique identifier in this case) to be repeated.

With this example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Gr3_PracMath_Jan11_D1 as a, student_list_011811 as b 
WHERE a.StudentID = b.StudentID
```

The field StudentID is repeated. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if you do an explicit join with the USING keyword, you won't get a duplicate.

```
SELECT *
FROM Gr3_PracMath_Jan11_D1
LEFT JOIN student_list_011811 
USING (StudentID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. You might cut your work by listing only half the fields:

```
SELECT a.*, b.Field1, b.Field2...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to not list out all of the columns, even if there are a lot of them. Just bite the bullet and write them out.