# Selecting distinct from joins in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables ie chatsTable and adsTable ... In chatsTable I have col_a_id(foreign key for ads) and col_message.
in ads I have multiple columns like col_title, col_desc. I need to join these tables and select distinct values.

```
SELECT ads.id,col_title,col_img,col_status FROM `adsTable` AS ads 
RIGHT JOIN `ChatsTable` AS chat ON (chat.a_id = ads.id) 
WHERE (`sender` = '1' OR `reciever` = '1') GROUP BY ads.id
```

This has worked for me but I want to merge col_message in this table. OR anything like that.

I have tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864848/sql-select-distinct-values-from-multiple-tables),[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552855/select-distinct-join-multiple-tables),[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730044/select-distinct-field-on-join-in-mysql) and much more..

Comment: update your question add  a proper data  sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - using distinct

```
SELECT distinct  ads.id,col_title,col_img,col_status,col_message
FROM `adsTable` AS ads 
RIGHT JOIN `ChatsTable` AS chat ON chat.a_id = ads.id
WHERE (`sender` = '1' OR `reciever` = '1')
```

Comment: I have tried distinct.. But the problem is that whenever I want to select the col_message.. the distinct is on no use there...

Comment: could you please add sample data in your question @user9514246